# Test convergence/ divergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:2^{-n-\left(-1\right)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals

I have no hint how to approach this problem.
Please Help!

Comment: Hint: the exponents are $0,-3,-2,-5,-4,-7,-6,-9\cdots$, or $0,-3,0-2,-3-2,0-4,-3-4,0-6,-3-6\cdots$.

Comment: This should remind you very much of $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\dots$ which you should know by example converges.

Comment: Each term is bounded by $2^{-n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $2^{-n-(-1)^n}=2^{-(n+(-1)^n)}=\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n+(-1)^n}=\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^n\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{(-1)^n}\leq\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^n2$. With this observation and a criteria for series convergent, you can argue and conclude that the series is convergent.

Comment: +1 Short and sweet :)